# Textarea value is equal to ""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I want to be able to change the value inside my textarea tag depending on what the user types.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Describe what happened</label>
    <textarea id="descriptionReport" form="newReport" placeholder="Describe what happened.." name="description" data-rule-describeEvent="true " cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control" maxlength="255" a></textarea>
</div>
```

I have declared a variable in my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var vm = {
       movieIds: [],
       ReportDescription: null
  };
```

And then I set it to the value inside the textarea tag

```
vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value;
```

The value i always get is equal to "".

I have added a validation plugin to check if the value is valid:

```
$.validator.addMethod("describeEvent", function () {
            return vm.ReportDescription !== "";
        }, "Please describe what happened.");
```

The sentence "Please describe what happened." appears no matter what i type in the textarea in my form.

I am fairly new to this and haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.

Comment: "depending on what the user types in the box". Wich box?

Comment: the box for text in my html form @SilverSurfer

Comment: Is it another input type  text in your form?

Comment: Your question is kinda strange you say that you want to set the value of the textarea depending what he types. And later you say that you get "" from the textarea. Something seems wrong here. If your textarea have to be filled following someother box it's normal that it stays emtpy isn't it?

Comment: Its not value,, use innerHtml
vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").innerHTML

Comment: I have 2 input tags of type text in my form, but they're working properly. The textarea is the one I'm currently having issues with. @SilverSurfer

Comment: @user5014677 how do i not keep it empty is my question? I want to set its value to whatever the user inputs and so far the only way i have been getting a proper value is if i hard-code the value otherwise i get the "Please describe what happened" error.

Comment: if you want to SET the value you do document.getElementById("yourTextareaID").value = value. if you want to GET the value it's value = document.getElementById("youtextareaID").value . Your question is confusing as you say that you want to set the value but then you do a get and yo usay that's it's empty.

Comment: @user5014677 i want to GET the value that the user types in but I am unable to.

Comment: var usersInput = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value; The user have to type inside the textarea. But in your question you say that he type in some other input. If he types in the textarea, this is how you get the value.

Comment: @user5014677 I still get the "Please describe what happened" validation even after the user types in the textarea.

I really appreciate your patience

Comment: Did you take a look at my answeR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comments i think that you simply don't change the value of vm once initialized on the read function that's why it stays empty and you get that message "Please describe what happened". I'm not aware of the plugin you're using but i assume that your ReportDescription stays at null the whole time and that's your problem.

HTML: I've added a keyup property to your textarea.

```
 <textarea id="descriptionReport" form="newReport" placeholder="Describe what happened.." name="description" data-rule-describeEvent="true " cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control" maxlength="255" onkeyup="applyChanges()"></textarea>
```

In your code add this function. It changes the value of vm.ReportDescription after the user pressed a key.

```
var vm;
$(document).ready(function () {
   vm = {
       movieIds: [],
       ReportDescription: null
  };
});
function applyChanges() { 
      vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value; 
      if (vm.ReportDescription == ""){
          vm.ReportDescription = null;
      }
}
```

Comment: getting error on console, Uncaught ReferenceError: applyChanges is not defined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeyup

Comment: Have you added the applyChanges() function to your js file?

Comment: when i add applyChanges() {
                vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value;
            } , I get expected ';' on the first curly bracket, where exactly in my code am i supposed to add it.

Comment: @IlirAs haha i forgot the keyword function :D

Comment: oh so it's : function applyChanges() {
                vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value;
            }

Comment: still getting the error, i added the function here
    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var vm = {
                movieIds: [],
                ReportDescription: null
            };

            function applyChanges() {
                vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value;
            }

Comment: You're getting the same error "not defined"? Maybe the browser doesn't take the modifications into account. Clean your browser's cache. You can also declar the vm outside the ready like var vm; and then inside the ready just do vm = {...

Comment: cleared cache and declared the var outside, error still occuring, Uncaught ReferenceError: applyChanges is not defined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeyup

Comment: Fixed it! I was typing it within the curly brackets of the other function. I just added it at the bottom and it's fixed. However when i type something and then remove and press submit it the message "Please describe what happened" doesn't appear even though it's empty. Otherwise it's working as planned.

Comment: @IlirAs Happens :) Tell me if it works now if yes accept answer if no we will search some other solution :p

Comment: when i type something and then delete it and then if i  press submit it the message "Please describe what happened" doesn't appear even though it's empty. Otherwise it's working as planned.

Comment: @IlirAs Check my update. Your plugin probably needs a null value or something so i just make sure to set it back to null if the textarea is empty.

Comment: ah yes i changed it from return vm.ReportDescription !== ""; to !== null earlier and that's why it wasnt appearing. Thank you SO much! I have literally spent the past 2 days trying to fix it and then i just thought i might open a stackoverflow acc and ask the question myself and voila!